# Adding a 0 at the end of the input when it is less than 9 digits

Tags: php, opencart

I have an e-commerce [site](http://oticasreiban.com.br/index.php?route=account/register) in opencart and I have a problem in the RG field which is as follows, when the user registers it fills all the fields normally but in the RG field there are those users that have one digit less in the RG that they are usually 9 more digits have users with 8 and they usually register on the site more when they are going to make a purchase they can not conclude it because the RG is with a number less would like to know if it is possible to put a code that does the following when the User to enter a RG with one digit less or less than 9 add a 0 at the end of the field so that it is complete.

This is uexatamente the input that I need to change so that when the user clicks on register it will be saved with the longest digit

```
<Input type = "text" name = "custom_field [account] [2]" value = "" placeholder = "RG" id = "input-custom-field2" class = "form-control">
```

I do not know if this is where I am going to implement my code but this is one of the controllers responsible for the registration of the form

```html
<?php
class ControllerAccountRegister extends Controller {
 private $error = array();

 public function index() {
  if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
   $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
  }

  $this->load->language('account/register');

  $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

  $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment.js');
  $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js');
  $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css');

  $this->load->model('account/customer');

  if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
   $customer_id = $this->model_account_customer->addCustomer($this->request->post);
   
   // Clear any previous login attempts for unregistered accounts.
   $this->model_account_customer->deleteLoginAttempts($this->request->post['email']);
   
   $this->customer->login($this->request->post['email'], $this->request->post['password']);

   unset($this->session->data['guest']);

   // Add to activity log
   $this->load->model('account/activity');

   $activity_data = array(
    'customer_id' => $customer_id,
    'name'        => $this->request->post['firstname']
    //'name'        => $this->request->post['firstname'] . ' ' . $this->request->post['lastname']
   );

   $this->model_account_activity->addActivity('register', $activity_data);

   $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/success'));
  }

  $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

  $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
   'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
   'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
  );

  $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
   'text' => $this->language->get('text_account'),
   'href' => $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL')
  );

  $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
   'text' => $this->language->get('text_register'),
   'href' => $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL')
  );

  $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

  $data['text_account_already'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_account_already'), $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
  $data['text_your_details'] = $this->language->get('text_your_details');
  $data['text_your_address'] = $this->language->get('text_your_address');
  $data['text_your_password'] = $this->language->get('text_your_password');
  $data['text_newsletter'] = $this->language->get('text_newsletter');
  $data['text_yes'] = $this->language->get('text_yes');
  $data['text_no'] = $this->language->get('text_no');
  $data['text_select'] = $this->language->get('text_select');
  $data['text_none'] = $this->language->get('text_none');
  $data['text_loading'] = $this->language->get('text_loading');

  $data['entry_customer_group'] = $this->language->get('entry_customer_group');
  $data['entry_firstname'] = $this->language->get('entry_firstname');
  // $data['entry_lastname'] = $this->language->get('entry_lastname');
  $data['entry_email'] = $this->language->get('entry_email');
  $data['entry_telephone'] = $this->language->get('entry_telephone');
  $data['entry_fax'] = $this->language->get('entry_fax');
  $data['entry_company'] = $this->language->get('entry_company');
  $data['entry_address_1'] = $this->language->get('entry_address_1');
  $data['entry_address_2'] = $this->language->get('entry_address_2');
  $data['entry_postcode'] = $this->language->get('entry_postcode');
  $data['entry_city'] = $this->language->get('entry_city');
  $data['entry_country'] = $this->language->get('entry_country');
  $data['entry_zone'] = $this->language->get('entry_zone');
  $data['entry_newsletter'] = $this->language->get('entry_newsletter');
  $data['entry_password'] = $this->language->get('entry_password');
  $data['entry_confirm'] = $this->language->get('entry_confirm');

  $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');
  $data['button_upload'] = $this->language->get('button_upload');

  if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
   $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
  } else {
   $data['error_warning'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->error['firstname'])) {
   $data['error_firstname'] = $this->error['firstname'];
  } else {
   $data['error_firstname'] = '';
  }

  // if (isset($this->error['lastname'])) {
  //  $data['error_lastname'] = $this->error['lastname'];
  // } else {
  //  $data['error_lastname'] = '';
  // }

  if (isset($this->error['email'])) {
   $data['error_email'] = $this->error['email'];
  } else {
   $data['error_email'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->error['telephone'])) {
   $data['error_telephone'] = $this->error['telephone'];
  } else {
   $data['error_telephone'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->error['address_1'])) {
   $data['error_address_1'] = $this->error['address_1'];
  } else {
   $data['error_address_1'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->error['city'])) {
   $data['error_city'] = $this->error['city'];
  } else {
   $data['error_city'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->error['postcode'])) {
   $data['error_postcode'] = $this->error['postcode'];
  } else {
   $data['error_postcode'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->error['country'])) {
   $data['error_country'] = $this->error['country'];
  } else {
   $data['error_country'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->error['zone'])) {
   $data['error_zone'] = $this->error['zone'];
  } else {
   $data['error_zone'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->error['custom_field'])) {
   $data['error_custom_field'] = $this->error['custom_field'];
  } else {
   $data['error_custom_field'] = array();
  }

  if (isset($this->error['password'])) {
   $data['error_password'] = $this->error['password'];
  } else {
   $data['error_password'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->error['confirm'])) {
   $data['error_confirm'] = $this->error['confirm'];
  } else {
   $data['error_confirm'] = '';
  }

  $data['action'] = $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL');

  $data['customer_groups'] = array();

  if (is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
   $this->load->model('account/customer_group');

   $customer_groups = $this->model_account_customer_group->getCustomerGroups();

   foreach ($customer_groups as $customer_group) {
    if (in_array($customer_group['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
     $data['customer_groups'][] = $customer_group;
    }
   }
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['customer_group_id'])) {
   $data['customer_group_id'] = $this->request->post['customer_group_id'];
  } else {
   $data['customer_group_id'] = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['firstname'])) {
   $data['firstname'] = $this->request->post['firstname'];
  } else {
   $data['firstname'] = '';
  }

  // if (isset($this->request->post['lastname'])) {
  //  $data['lastname'] = $this->request->post['lastname'];
  // } else {
  //  $data['lastname'] = '';
  // }

  if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
   $data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
  } else {
   $data['email'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['telephone'])) {
   $data['telephone'] = $this->request->post['telephone'];
  } else {
   $data['telephone'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['fax'])) {
   $data['fax'] = $this->request->post['fax'];
  } else {
   $data['fax'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['company'])) {
   $data['company'] = $this->request->post['company'];
  } else {
   $data['company'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['address_1'])) {
   $data['address_1'] = $this->request->post['address_1'];
  } else {
   $data['address_1'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['address_2'])) {
   $data['address_2'] = $this->request->post['address_2'];
  } else {
   $data['address_2'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['postcode'])) {
   $data['postcode'] = $this->request->post['postcode'];
  } elseif (isset($this->session->data['shipping_address']['postcode'])) {
   $data['postcode'] = $this->session->data['shipping_address']['postcode'];
  } else {
   $data['postcode'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['city'])) {
   $data['city'] = $this->request->post['city'];
  } else {
   $data['city'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['country_id'])) {
   $data['country_id'] = $this->request->post['country_id'];
  } elseif (isset($this->session->data['shipping_address']['country_id'])) {
   $data['country_id'] = $this->session->data['shipping_address']['country_id'];
  } else {
   $data['country_id'] = $this->config->get('config_country_id');
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['zone_id'])) {
   $data['zone_id'] = $this->request->post['zone_id'];
  } elseif (isset($this->session->data['shipping_address']['zone_id'])) {
   $data['zone_id'] = $this->session->data['shipping_address']['zone_id'];
  } else {
   $data['zone_id'] = '';
  }

  $this->load->model('localisation/country');

  $data['countries'] = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountries();

  // Custom Fields
  $this->load->model('account/custom_field');

  $data['custom_fields'] = $this->model_account_custom_field->getCustomFields();

  if (isset($this->request->post['custom_field'])) {
   if (isset($this->request->post['custom_field']['account'])) {
    $account_custom_field = $this->request->post['custom_field']['account'];
   } else {
    $account_custom_field = array();
   }
   
   if (isset($this->request->post['custom_field']['address'])) {
    $address_custom_field = $this->request->post['custom_field']['address'];
   } else {
    $address_custom_field = array();
   }   
   
   $data['register_custom_field'] = $account_custom_field + $address_custom_field;
  } else {
   $data['register_custom_field'] = array();
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['password'])) {
   $data['password'] = $this->request->post['password'];
  } else {
   $data['password'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['confirm'])) {
   $data['confirm'] = $this->request->post['confirm'];
  } else {
   $data['confirm'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['newsletter'])) {
   $data['newsletter'] = $this->request->post['newsletter'];
  } else {
   $data['newsletter'] = '';
  }

  if ($this->config->get('config_account_id')) {
   $this->load->model('catalog/information');

   $information_info = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformation($this->config->get('config_account_id'));

   if ($information_info) {
    $data['text_agree'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_agree'), $this->url->link('information/information/agree', 'information_id=' . $this->config->get('config_account_id'), 'SSL'), $information_info['title'], $information_info['title']);
   } else {
    $data['text_agree'] = '';
   }
  } else {
   $data['text_agree'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['agree'])) {
   $data['agree'] = $this->request->post['agree'];
  } else {
   $data['agree'] = false;
  }

  $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
  $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
  $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
  $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
  $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
  $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

  if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/account/register.tpl')) {
   $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/account/register.tpl', $data));
  } else {
   $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/account/register.tpl', $data));
  }
 }

 public function validate() {
  if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['firstname'])) > 32)) {
   $this->error['firstname'] = $this->language->get('error_firstname');
  }

  // if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['lastname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['lastname'])) > 32)) {
  //  $this->error['lastname'] = $this->language->get('error_lastname');
  // }

  if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['email']) > 96) || !preg_match('/^[^\@]+@.*.[a-z]{2,15}$/i', $this->request->post['email'])) {
   $this->error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
  }

  if ($this->model_account_customer->getTotalCustomersByEmail($this->request->post['email'])) {
   $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_exists');
  }

  if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) > 32)) {
   $this->error['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone');
  }

  if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['address_1'])) < 3) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['address_1'])) > 128)) {
   $this->error['address_1'] = $this->language->get('error_address_1');
  }

  if ((utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['city'])) < 2) || (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['city'])) > 128)) {
   $this->error['city'] = $this->language->get('error_city');
  }

  $this->load->model('localisation/country');

  $country_info = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountry($this->request->post['country_id']);

  if ($country_info && $country_info['postcode_required'] && (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['postcode'])) < 2 || utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['postcode'])) > 10)) {
   $this->error['postcode'] = $this->language->get('error_postcode');
  }

  if ($this->request->post['country_id'] == '') {
   $this->error['country'] = $this->language->get('error_country');
  }

  if (!isset($this->request->post['zone_id']) || $this->request->post['zone_id'] == '') {
   $this->error['zone'] = $this->language->get('error_zone');
  }

  // Customer Group
  if (isset($this->request->post['customer_group_id']) && is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display')) && in_array($this->request->post['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
   $customer_group_id = $this->request->post['customer_group_id'];
  } else {
   $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
  }

  // Custom field validation
  $this->load->model('account/custom_field');

  $custom_fields = $this->model_account_custom_field->getCustomFields($customer_group_id);

  foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
   if ($custom_field['required'] && empty($this->request->post['custom_field'][$custom_field['location']][$custom_field['custom_field_id']])) {
    $this->error['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);
   }
  }

  if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['password']) < 4) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['password']) > 20)) {
   $this->error['password'] = $this->language->get('error_password');
  }

  if ($this->request->post['confirm'] != $this->request->post['password']) {
   $this->error['confirm'] = $this->language->get('error_confirm');
  }

  // Agree to terms
  if ($this->config->get('config_account_id')) {
   $this->load->model('catalog/information');

   $information_info = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformation($this->config->get('config_account_id'));

   if ($information_info && !isset($this->request->post['agree'])) {
    $this->error['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_agree'), $information_info['title']);
   }
  }

  return !$this->error;
 }

 public function customfield() {
  $json = array();

  $this->load->model('account/custom_field');

  // Customer Group
  if (isset($this->request->get['customer_group_id']) && is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display')) && in_array($this->request->get['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
   $customer_group_id = $this->request->get['customer_group_id'];
  } else {
   $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
  }

  $custom_fields = $this->model_account_custom_field->getCustomFields($customer_group_id);

  foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
   $json[] = array(
    'custom_field_id' => $custom_field['custom_field_id'],
    'required'        => $custom_field['required']
   );
  }

  $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
  $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
 }
}
```

Comment: See [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks for the answer I will check when the user finishes the registration he will be savo in the database and goes to the panel of opencart with this data and if his Rg is with a number unless this function will be in charge of adding this number to more ?

Answer (score 2):

may be you can use this script.

```
function putZeroToLastItem($text) {
    $length  = strlen($text);

    if( $length < 9 ) {
       $text .= '0'
    }

    return $text
}
```

I hope , this script will solve your porblem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add 0 after the number (9 digit)? Use jquery if you want it in client side.

```
    function addZero (data){
     return  data+(data <10 ? '0':'');
 }

    var num =$('#number').val();
     var nNum = addZero(num);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Friend when the user type in the form a rg that does not contain 9 digits this rg would have to be saved with a digit 0 to be able to complete all the digits or it registers with 8 more then the system adds a digit 0 at the end of the RG more so Being is less than 9

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$num = 3;
$num_padded = sprintf("%02d", $num);
echo $num_padded; // returns 03
?>
```

Try this simple snippet

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'm new to programming and already I have to fix an e-commerce that I do not have much knowledge that would be exactly the input that would have to add the extra digit if it is filled with less than 9 digits <input type="text" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="RG" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control"> the user will fill normally after clicking on register if you have With less than 9 digits there the code inserts a 0 at the end of the RG if it has the 9 digits does nothing

Comment: @Mujeeby Rahman Friend I added your code inside the register.php file which is what is being displayed in the code in my question it displays the number 3 now I just need to know how can I link this to my input

Answer (score 0):

A reduced way of @mehfatitem:

```
function putZeroToLastItem($text) {
    return (strlen($text) < 9) ? $text . '0' : $text;
}
```